# How to place button at the end of form, but when AutoScroll = true

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple `GroupBox`'s, and that's why I set `AutoScroll` to true. I create all controls in Form_Load. How to place one button after all `GroupBox`'es?

The code, where I create `GroupBox`es:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
                gb.Name = "GroupBox" + (i + 1);
                gb.Size = new Size(500, 200);
                gb.Location = new Point(40, loc);
                gb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine;

                Label q_text = new Label(); // текст питання
                q_text.Name = "label" + (i + 1);
                q_text.Text = "Питання" + (i + 1);
                q_text.Font = new Font("Aria", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                q_text.Location = new Point(10, 10);
                gb.Controls.Add(q_text);
                int iter = q_text.Location.Y + 30;
                if (i <= 5)
                {
                    foreach (string key in questions[i].answers.Keys)
                    {
                        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                        rb.Text = key;
                        rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
                        rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
                        iter += 30;
                        gb.Controls.Add(rb);
                    }
                }else
                    if (i > 5)
                    {
                        foreach (string key in questions[i].answers.Keys)
                        {
                            CheckBox rb = new CheckBox();
                            rb.Text = key;
                            rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
                            rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
                            iter += 30;
                            gb.Controls.Add(rb);
                        }

                    }                

                this.Controls.Add(gb);
                loc += 200;
```

Comment: Are you using a FlowLayoutPanel or what? We need to see some of your code!

Comment: btn.Location = new Point(40, loc);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place all the scrollable group boxes in one panel which is set to AutoScroll = true. Below this panel is another one containing the fixed button. This panel is docked to the bottom.

Comment: Looks like I correctly guessed what he wanted to do ;D

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `loc` variable, you can do:

```
btnMyButton.Locaction= new Point(40, loc);
```

Anyway, if you want to find the position of the last group box dynamically, try this:

```
double leftPos=0,topPos=0;
foreach(Control c in Forms.Controls)
{
    if(c.Name=="GroupBox")
    {
        if(c.Left>leftPos)
            leftPos=c.Left;
        if(c.Top>topPos)
            topPos=c.Top;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I find the last groupbox?  int this.Controls.  I can;t find propriate method

Comment: @user3528837: You are creating group boxes dynamically, right? So the code where you create them.

Comment: I think so too. But I try to use your method

Comment: @user3528837: You have a `loc` variable. Then why do you need to find it dynamically? Anyway, added it to my answer.